# The type Prevayler is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <P>

Tags: java, fault-tolerance, checkpoint, prevayler

I have been reading about checkpointing technique for fault tolerance. So, I am working with `prevayler` java library for checkpointing. Now, I have a error showed The type `Prevayler` is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments `<P>`. Can you give me guidance for this error?

**Here is my code:**

```
import org.prevayler.Prevayler;
import org.prevayler.PrevaylerFactory;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public final class PrevaylerSample {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        final Prevayler prevayler = PrevaylerFactory.createPrevayler(new   ArrayList<String>());

        prevayler.execute(new SampleTransaction());

        prevayler.takeSnapshot();

        prevayler.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I got compiler error in `PrevaylerFactory.createPrevayler(new   ArrayList<String>())` so I cannot see any result.

Comment: Also, make sure you are targeting java >= 1.5

Answer (score 0):

Your current declaration of `Prevayler` uses raw type at the moment. Have you tried to parametrized it ?

```
final Prevayler<ArrayList<String>> prevayler = PrevaylerFactory.createPrevayler(new ArrayList<String>());
```